# Converting an Image DataUrl to Image

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to take picture using webcam in my java web application.Now to do this i am using Photobooth.js that provide facility to click images in web applications.

Now my problem is that as soon as I click button to take picture I want to save it in my computer with a name say temp.png in a specified folder say C:/MyPictures.But the picture being clicked by using photobooth.js provides a dataUrl of the form :

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU and so on a long string.
```

How can i get image to specified location now?

My code for using photobooth and displaying the clicked image is as follow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#photo').photobooth().on("image", function (event, dataUrl) {
        alert(dataUrl);

        $("#gallery").show().html('<img src="' + dataUrl + '" >');
        });
 });
 </script>
```

In html part :

```
<div id="photo"></div>
<div id="gallery"></div>
```

Here is the .js file am using :

https://github.com/WolframHempel/photobooth-js/blob/gh-pages/photobooth_min.js

I got this code to convert dataURL to blob .Can it be helpful in getting me image to particular location ?

```
function dataURLtoBlob(dataUrl) {
        // Decode the dataURL    
        var binary = atob(dataUrl.split(',')[1]);

        // Create 8-bit unsigned array
        var array = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
            array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
        }

        // Return our Blob object
        return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {
        type: 'image/png'
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to trigger a download from javascript?

Comment: @DeclanCook Yeah,You can say so ,Download but download to a specified folder of my computer.

Answer (score 2):

Are you just trying to trigger a download of the image? You can download a file in javascript using an anchor element with a download attribute and firing a click event on it. In this case you could set the anchors href to be the dataURL of your image.

```
function download(dataUrl, filename) {
    var download = document.createElement('a');
    download.href = dataUrl;
    download.target = '_blank';
    download.download = filename;
    var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                       false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    download.dispatchEvent(evt);

}
```

See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/edAAe/1/

Comment: I  want that as soon as i click camera option to take the image then a copy of the image gets automatically saved in a folder in my computer.Also the code provided by you downloads a corrupted file.No image

Comment: I don't think you can save to a specific folder due to browser security restrictions.

Comment: I was  thinking of to store it in database as blob and then retrieve it as image.What say?Will it work ?

Comment: Unless the database is on the client you still wont be able to save it directly into a specific folder. Also there is no need to retrieve it as an image as the dataURL can be treated as an image.

Comment: Am making a web application means am doing server side programming.So am asking that can this image be stored as Blob in database coresponding to that user and then use this blob in my jsp /servlets

Comment: The filename is not set :( (Works on Firefox, fails in Chrome!)